# TypeError: 'Kon' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, typeerror

I've this object called Kon

```
class Kon:

    def __init__(self, cId, isP, fsn = "", snoId = "", synDesc = "", preDesc = ""):
        self.conceptId = cId
        self.isprimitive = isP
        self.fullySpecifiedName = fsn
        #self.ctv3id = 
        self.snomedId = snoId
        #self.conceptStatus = ""
        self.synonymDesc= synDesc
        self.preferredDesc = preDesc
```

and this function in another class:

```
class ConceptList():

  def sct2fsn(self,sctId):
        c = self.zerrenda.get(sctId,'')
        if c:
            return c["fullySpecifiedName"]
        else:
            return ""
```

Why am I getting this Type error?

```
  File "/klaseak.py", line 169, in sct2fsn
    return c["fullySpecifiedName"]
TypeError: 'Kon' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: What is `kontzeptuaJaso`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow you got the idea that you should access data from your object as if it were a dictionary.

```
 return c["fullySpecifiedName"]
```

But you haven't implemented `__getitem__` for your class, so you can't use the `[...]` notation to retrieve items from it.

You probably want to just use regular attribute access to access that attribute:

```
return c.fullySpecifiedName
```